# IPN for s2member

Tags: s2member

I want to integrate a local gateway. So planned to receive the response from local gateway to ipnhandler.php (for example) and then ipnhandler will sent post data to s2m via cURL.

I need to know how the parameters should be. I've tried with a demo form but nothing was happened, no log, no message. So need your help.

Form was

```
<form action="http://example.com/s2m/?s2member_paypal_notify=1&s2member_paypal_proxy=LocalGate&s2member_paypal_proxy_verification=905e5a3c73480046f4354946788b8ea1" method="POST">
<input type="hidden" name="first_name" value="Tanmoy" />
<input type="hidden" name="last_name" value="SK" />
<input type="hidden" name="custom" value="example.com" />
<input type="hidden" name="item_number" value="1:hello" />
<input type="hidden" name="txn_type" value="w4324rewq423" />
<input type="hidden" name="payer_email" value="1234@mail.com" />
<input type="hidden" name="period" value="30" />
<input type="hidden" name="mc_amount" value="30" />
<input type="hidden" name="recurring" value="1" />
<input type="submit">
</form>
```

They have a documentation on it also, can be found [here](http://www.primothemes.com/forums/viewtopic.php?f=36&t=3154).

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use [`wp_remote_post()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_API/wp_remote_post) for that task.

```
wp_remote_post(
     'http://example.com/s2m/?s2member_paypal_notify=1&s2member_paypal_proxy=LocalGate&s2member_paypal_proxy_verification=905e5a3c73480046f4354946788b8ea1'
    ,array(
         'method'     => 'POST'
        ,'timeout'    => 30
        ,'redirect'   => 5
        ,'user-agent' => 'my-app/1.0'
        ,'blocking'   => true
        ,'compress'   => false
        ,'sslverify'  => false
     )
);
```

Note that all `$args` (the 2nd argument/array) have default options. You can read more about it [in the Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/HTTP_API#Other_Arguments).

Comment: I'm not facing issue to send data, my issue is that the format I'm using isn't correct perhaps. For s2memeber, I need to know correct format to send data to PayPal proxy IPN handler.

Comment: @InfinityQuery Then your question is off topic here.

Comment: s2member is a WordPress plugin, and I want to add an additional gateway there.
So why it's an off topic?

Comment: @InfinityQuery Because it's about the query args you need to get that service running. This is a problem with the service and not with WordPress.

Comment: So adding an gateway in a WordPress plugin is an off topic in this forum?

Comment: @InfinityQuery Adding _remote request_ a gateway? Maybe not. But asking what query args you need to get the correct _response_ **is** off topic, as it's a problem with the service, not with WordPress. Use [RedBot](http://redbot.org) or [HTTPstatus](http://httpstatus.nl/) to test your request. When you got a working query string and got problems handling the data or doing the request with WP internals, then come back and rework your question.

Comment: You probably missed to catch my point. Or I was failed to tell.
I'll forward the received (from my gateway) response to s2member. S2member Free version cannot process returned response from other gateway (Only payapl). So using a php file I'll process the response (from my gateway) so that s2member can understand that.
I followed this link http://www.primothemes.com/forums/viewtopic.php?f=36&t=3154 and tried to do using a form. But nothing was happened.

Comment: Ok, so the paid version does support that? Also why aren't you using their support forum?

Comment: They won't answer support related questions from non-paying users.

Comment: In your case I'd simply invest those bucks. At least you're creating a paid service, so investing a little bit should be ok. Anyway, the discussion is too long now, so I'll stop here.